# How to check length of array in json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Say that I have the following Json in a cookie file representing a simple customer basket.

```
{"merc":[
   {"id":"2","nrOfItems":"1"},
   {"id":"4","nrOfItems":"2"}
]
}
```

now say that I want to make sure that **merch** isn't empty, in that case I want to print out "your basket is empty". How can I do that? I only know how to make use of the $.each function.

```
    cookiee= readCookie("merchBasket");

            object = cookiee.toString();
            obj = JSON.parse(object);
            if(Merch isn't empty){//How can I check the length of merch?
            $.each(obj.merc, function() { 
                    //Print out the merch
            }); 
}
else{
document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML=   "your basket is empty";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```
if(obj.merc.length > 0) {
  // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept your answer when its possible =)

Answer (score 0):

Its very straight forward

Just use the `.length` property on object.

Here is  fiddle. run the fiddle to see the length.

```
var m = {"merc":[
   {"id":"2","nrOfItems":"1"},
   {"id":"4","nrOfItems":"2"}
]
}
alert(m.merc.length) //it shows length 2
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhfWL/)